# Forcing a borrow with the `Into` trait

Tags: rust

```
struct Foo(i32);

impl<'a> Into<i32> for &'a Foo {
    fn into(self) -> i32 {
        self.0
    }
}

fn test<I: Into<i32>>(i: I) {
    let n: i32 = i.into();
    println!("{}", n);
}

fn main() {
    let f = Foo(42);
    test(&f);
}
```

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=f830df84955fb029f4d90e96b6a60e51&version=stable&backtrace=0)

This works but just looking at `test`

```
fn test<I: Into<i32>>(i: I) {
    let n: i32 = i.into();
    println!("{}", n);
}
```

The function can access both a borrow and a move/copy depending on how the `Into` trait is implemented.

```
impl<'a> Into<i32> for &'a Foo
// vs
impl Into<i32> for Foo
```

Now the user could try to call test like `test(f);` instead of `test(&f);` and would receive the following error message.

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `i32: std::convert::From<Foo>` is not satisfied
  --> <anon>:16:5
   |
16 |     test(f);
   |     ^^^^ trait `i32: std::convert::From<Foo>` not satisfied
   |
```

Would it be possible to always force a borrow? Something similar to this

```
fn test<I: Into<i32>>(i: &I) {
    let n: i32 = i.into();
    println!("{}", n);
}
```

So that the user would get an error message similar to, "Expected &XX but found YY".

Comment: I am a bit confused on what you're trying to achieve here. Do you want to change the compiler's error message under that situation? Also note that you should preferably impl [`From`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/convert/trait.From.html) instead of `Into`.

Comment: @E_net4 A clearer error message.

Answer (score 0):

A `where`-clause works here by specifying the lifetime:

```rust
fn test<'a, I>(i: &'a I) where &'a I: Into<i32> {
    let n: i32 = i.into();
    println!("{}", n);
}
```

Now when you attempt to build with `test(f);`, the message is clearer:

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/main.rs:16:10
   |
16 |     test(f);
   |          ^
   |          |
   |          expected `&Foo`, found struct `Foo`
   |          help: consider borrowing here: `&f`
```